# How to find pixels color in particular coordinate in images?

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel

I have one activity, my activity contains one ImageView.I have implemented OnTouchListener for ImageView.Here I want find pixels color where i touch in image.Please let me know how to find pixels color.I have one ideas,

-->In ImageView where i touch just find X and Y coordinate and find pixels in same X and Y   coordinate and find pixels color.Please let me is it possible.

Please  give any suggestion or document for to do this please.

with ur reference i wrote code for bitmap,

```
int mId=R.drawable.with_colors;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mId);
bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

In onTouch

```
int x=(int) event.getX();
int y=(int) event.getY();
int color=bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
Log.d("colors","---"+color);
```

But here Log printing "Colors---0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29) method of the imageview to get what is drawn, and then get the bitmap from that by casting to `BitmapDrawable` and calling [`getBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29):

```
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

To get the coordinates, assign an [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html):

```
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            //TODO: get pixel at x, y

            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
});
```

In the code above you can basically just insert the first code where it says "get pixel at x, y" to get the pixel color.

Comment: how to find coordinate where i touch? please help me

Comment: @Chiru hm, first of all, the `Bitmap.copy()` is redundant as you have already read the bitmap with a lower bit depth than 32bit, you should instead use the BitmapFactory.Options and set inPreferredConfig to ARGB_8888: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: @Chiru secondly, as to why `getPixel()` returns 0; I don't know. Try logging the x and y values too to make sure that they are correct. Also make sure that the bitmap is loaded properly by testing `getPixel()` on some points where you know what the result should be.

Comment: Here i got x and y values but why getPixel() returns 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8711/discussion-between-chiru-and-jave)