# How to counting number of pixel every region in a binary image ( Android )

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

I take photo of two  object. I removing noise, convert RGB to Grayscale, improve the contrast and convert Grayscale to biner. Finally,I wanna counting number of pixel every region in this case can see the picture. How I counting the every region in android ? do i have to detect the square region in advance? and decreasing the total number of pixels with pixel square region ? Any idea? What algorithm should I use ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the steps you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to "count" all black pixels, for example, you need to perform two loops (one horizontal and one vertical) at image. Something like this:

```
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
for(int x = 0; x < imageView.getWidth();x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < imageView.getWidth();y++){
        int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        // here you have the color
    }
}
```

[code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632189/2649418)

Comment: thank you. But in this case,I want to count pixel every region,  number pixel of the square region  & number pixel of the other region. Not count all black pixel.

Comment: I have a problem for count every region from two object in a binary image. can you help me for solve my problem ? thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: first of all, your image must be a "Drawable" instance, ok? The image always will have 2 colors?

Answer (score 0):

You could invert your image and then sum up every pixel in the bounding rectangle of your Contour. Since Black=0 and White=1 The sum of the inverted Blacks will be the number of Black Pixels in your contour. As long as there is no other contour in your bounding rectangle it should work fine.